# Create just one button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a HTML button that when you click on it, calls a function. The function is below:

```
function newButton ()
{
 let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 btn.innerHTML = "Click me";
 document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

I need it so the HTML button can only call this function once (so that it only creates 1 button) otherwise, if you continue clicking the original HTML button, it will just continue creating more new buttons.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without extending further about your scenario, it's almost impossible to answer this right

Comment: Hello James and welcome to SO, I suggest you read the following article on how to create a minimal reproducible example and add more content to your question so the community will have the tools they need to assist with your question/s... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to keep track of the state in a variable.  Something like:

```
let created = false;

function newButton () {
  if (!created) {
    // your code
    created = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `addEventListener` you could listen for an event only once by setting the `once` option to `true`. This will remove the event listener after `newButton` has been called.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('create-button');

function newButton () {
 let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 btn.innerHTML = "Click me";
 document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

button.addEventListener('click', newButton, { once: true });
```

```html
<button id="create-button">Create Button, but only once.</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if button exists, with ID or class exists. If it doesn't create new one. In other case - do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add a `if` statement and a var (int if you want to create lets say several, boolean if only one), something like that:

```
var btnAmount = 1;

function newButton ()
{
  if(btnAmount == 1) {
    //do your thing and create the button
    btnAmount--;
  }
}
```

Comment: remember you need `==` or `===` to compare in the `if` statement

Comment: @germanio true! I spaced out right there hehe

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, without knowing much more about your specific scenario:

```
function newButton ()
{
 let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 btn.innerHTML = "Click me";
 document.body.appendChild(btn);
 newButton = () => {};
}
```

If you're invoking this function from an event handler, you could set the [`once` option on `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Doing so will only invoke the method once, while removing the handler for subsequent invocations.

[illustration](https://jsfiddle.net/hcsvLfx2/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function newButton ()
{
    let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = "Click me";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener('click', newButton, { once: true });
}

document.getElementById('rootButton').addEventListener('click',newButton);
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Create Buttons" id='rootButton'>
```